# How to score a document using a lexicon with weights?

Tags: nlp, nltk

I have a lexicon which has about 40,000 members of of ngram length `[1, 3]` and an associated weight for each lexicon member. It is a fairly simple task: I just want to "score" a document by adding the weight of each lexicon member that appears in the document.

But I am unsure how to do it for lexicon members that are bigrams or trigrams?

```
import re

lexicon = [
    ("text", 3), 
    ("a lot", 2), 
    ("string", 1),
    ("has a lot", 2)
]

text = "This is a text. It has a lot of text in it. It is a string, too. Let's rate it."


def score_text(text):
  """
  Score a document by iterating through a lexicon and adding the score
  of each lexicon member that appears in the document

  NOTE: AS OF NOW THIS ONLY WORKS FOR NGRAM=1
  """
  text = text.lower() #lowercase
  text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',text) #no punct
  text = text.split() #split str

  # Score how many times a word appears in text
  # Multiply the word's weight by its occurrence 
  score = sum([w[1]*text.count(w[0]) for w in lexicon])

  return score

print(score_text(text))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is to use regex to match the words. But this will count the occurrences of all i.e in your example, `'a lot' and 'has a lot'` both would be counted.

```
def score_text(text):
  text = text.lower() #lowercase
  text = re.sub(r'[^\w\s\.]','',text) #no punct  
  score = 0

  for w in lexicon:
    count = len(re.findall(re.escape(w[0]), text))
    score += count * w[1]

  return score

print(score_text(text))
11
```

Comment: I actually do want bot to be counted